# Terrafom variable not set by environmental variable with prefix TF_VAR_

Tags: terraform

I am facing a problem trying to use environmental variables to set terraform variables with the prefix TF_VAR_

This is my .env

```
TF_VAR_test=test
```

This is my _env.tf

```
variable "test"{
    type = string
}
```

This is my main.tf

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "CarlosAlejandroGuerreroMartinez"

    workspaces {
      name = "pokemon-team-manager-github-actions"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
(base) carloswarrior@Carloss-MacBook-Pro devops % source .env 
(base) carloswarrior@Carloss-MacBook-Pro devops % echo $TF_VAR_test
test
(base) carloswarrior@Carloss-MacBook-Pro devops % terraform plan 
Running plan in Terraform Cloud. Output will stream here. Pressing Ctrl-C
will stop streaming the logs, but will not stop the plan running remotely.

Preparing the remote plan...

To view this run in a browser, visit:
https://app.terraform.io/app/CarlosAlejandroGuerreroMartinez/pokemon-team-manager-github-actions/runs/run-7SC5B4eqg3ySq4Kv

Waiting for the plan to start...

Terraform v1.6.3
on linux_amd64
Initializing plugins and modules...
╷
│ Error: No value for required variable
│ 
│   on _env.tf line 10:
│   10: variable "test"{
│ 
│ The root module input variable "test" is not set, and has no default value.
│ Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for this
│ variable.
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.
```

[image: Code and execution]

Answer (score -1):

here is the sample declaration

```
resource "example_resource" "example" {
  some_attribute = var.test
}

# Define the variable
variable "test" {
  type = string
}
```